# Creating a drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a question on creating a drop down menu for a web page. I want a drop down menu hovering over my text and don't know how to create it and been trying to do one but still stuck. Is anyone willing to help? Also, create it with CSS.

Here's where I wanted.

```
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Women</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Men</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Children</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: What CSS have you tried? your list seems like there is no "top" value to drop down from? What do you want the end result to look like?

Comment: You should Google exactly what you have in your question header and you will see many examples. Here is one tutorial walkthrough on what you are asking: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it right, you want a drop down to occur when you hover over the text of the drop-down.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <h2>Dropdown Menu</h2>
    <p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">My Links</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Women</a>
            <a href="#">Men</a>
            <a href="#">Children</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle of it.
https://jsfiddle.net/x1rhveLh/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure css solution. You can show the `dropdown-menu` when you hover on the `dropdown-trigger`.

```css
.dropdown-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-wrapper:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block !important;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-wrapper">
  <p class="dropdown-trigger">Show dropdown on hover</p>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Women</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Men</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Children</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You should make the dropdown stay so you can click its links.

Comment: @jack thanks, I updated my code, now the menu will stay and you can click on it.